# DataGrip current statement highlighting

Tags: datagrip

I installed DataGrip and spent a couple hours getting rid of bells and whistles that distract me from editing sql, like the lightbulb. I'm down to this one that for my life I can't figure, so when I move around with the caret, the editor comes up with what it thinks is the current statement and draws a thin border around it, say if it's a line ending in a semicolon, it will border just that line, but if I have several statements each not ending in semicolon, it will think they all make up a single one and draw the rectangle around the whole thing. This in itself is distracting, plus if I hit Enter within the border, it will indent differently according to what it thinks the whole thing is. I just want Enter to go to a new line at the 0, leftmost position.

Is there any way to turn the whole feature off completely?

Apart from that, does anyone know if it's possible to get DataGrip to display the number of rows affected after an INSERT or UPDATE, like most other tools do?

I'm using it with Postgresql. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cpp_developer! (By the way, what do you think about CLion? :)
There are several questions in one, let's get answers one by one.

1. Lightbulb: there is no UI for getting rid of it, but there is the way. It is described in this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94381
   TLDR:

> Following line should be added to the
>   $IDE_CONFIG_HOME/options/editor.xml then:

```html
<option name="SHOW_INTENTION_BULB" value="false" />
```

2. Line showing the current statement.

It can be removed, like any other color/font thing: A small helpful action. For now it is only present in the Find Action menu (Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+A), but as usual, you can assign any shortcut to it.

[image]

This action will navigate you to the settings which are relevant to the context under the caret. If there are several of them, just choose one. In your case "Statement to execute". Then remove it or make white.

[image]

3. Smart indenting. Just turn this off: 
   [image]
4. Number of INSERTed and UPDATEd rows can be found in Output tab. But please, run them in batch mode -> context menu "Run %your_console%.sql"
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer moscas. Those are exactly the answers I was looking for. I had spent hours looking through the Font and Colors Menus and changing things but missed the whole Database submenu. I got rid of the border by setting the reparse delay to something like 999999999. Now I changed it back to a couple miliseconds but somehow I can't make the border come back. Good riddance :). Either way if does, Statement to execute looks like the correct place to turn it off (it does have the green border Effect turned on currently).

Comment: I had found that DataGrip does indeed show the number of rows affected except if it's 0, it just says "completed in xx miliseconds", rather than "0 rows affected", good enough, it just confused me at first. 

I had one more thing that I wanted to turn off, there is this default toolbar that has the green Run button, the "Autocommit checkbox", parameters "P" icon and Settings button, I can't find how to hide it, I turned off every available toolbar and in the Options where you customize the buttons on toolbars, this one doesn't seem to be listed at all.

Comment: Also I found an "Enter non-distraction" mode in the Edit menu, but it does a weird thing, it puts a whole lot of blank space to the left of the text, between the window edge and the beginning of text, I wonder how that's useful and whether there's any way to turn off. 
I like the no-distraction, versus manually turning off everything because in no-distraction you also don't have the name of the file in the tab label shown at the top, which I don't care for and I can't find how to turn off in no-non-distraction.

Comment: never used clion, I used to love IntelliJ when I did Java work, and for C++ have been using VStudio and emacs + command line for Linux. Glad to hear there's something cross platform out there, Linux sorely lacked decent IDE's for the longest time, will definitely give it a try on my next Linux stint )

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but there is no way to turn off this panel in non-distraction mode. And there is no way to left-align the text in the distraction free mode. But it'll make sense, for sure. We'll consider this.